# HTML error with head tag

Tags: html

[image: code error]

> Error: Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>
> From line 7, column 1; to line 7, column 6
>
> `=1.0">↩↩↩↩<head>↩    <`

Comment: It seems, that you have two head tags in your html

Comment: i looked through my code and could not find any other head tags. i have a closing one

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: its more than 15 characters

Comment: its alot of characters

Comment: The engine inserts a `<head>` automatically when you start adding content that belongs inside a `<head>`. The `<meta>` tag on line 3 is in the wrong place.

Comment: thanks man it worked

Comment: @JJJ that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write the first `<meta>` tag inside the `<head>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Monster Wiki</title>
.
.
.
.
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **head** tag contains **meta** tag . By default if you don't use the **html** , **body** , **head** tags , the browser adds them by default wherever it deems it appropriate ... so a **head** tag is added before and after **meta** tag and when you add a **head** tag again its a duplicate entry...